# scala value class multiple inheritance

Tags: scala, inheritance, value-class

I have in my project objects that represent IDs.

Let's say it is ChairId, TableId, LampId. I want them all to inherit from GenericId. And I want to be able to call `def f(x: GenericId) = x.id`

I want them to hold only single `id: String` so I would like to make them extend AnyVal.

Also I would like for each type to provide function `generate` which would generate my specific ID i.e. I would like to type something like `ChairId.generate()`

I have typed this:

```
sealed abstract class GenericId(val id: String)
final case class ChairId(override val id: String) extends GenericId(id)
final case class TableId(override val id: String) extends GenericId(id
```

And I though if GenericId would inherit from AnyVal that would work but so far no luck ;/ I also tried making GenericId a trait and make case classes extend AnyVal with GenericId but also won't compile :/

Another thing with `TableId.generate()` I can provide companion object just with function `generate` and that basically solve my problem but I wondered if there is possibility to solve that without defining companion object? (i.e. through implicits somehow)

// edit

regarding comment to provide code which doesn't compile(and I would like to):

```
sealed abstract class AbstractId(val id: String) extends AnyVal
final case class CatId(override val id: String) extends AbstractId(id)
final case class DogId(override val id: String) extends AbstractId(id)
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking here. If there are multiple questions, you may want to split them up into multiple Stack Overflow questions.

Comment: Please include the code and the compile errors for the things that you've tried. I think that would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Value classes cannot work this way for a couple of reasons.

First, from the [documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html), value classes cannot be extended by any other class, so `AbstractId` cannot extend `AnyVal`. ([Limitation #7](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html#summary-of-limitations))

```
scala> abstract class AbstractId(val id: String) extends AnyVal
<console>:10: error: `abstract' modifier cannot be used with value classes
       abstract class AbstractId(val id: String) extends AnyVal
                      ^
```

Second, *even if* you make `AbstractId` a trait, and define the other ids like this:

```
final case class DogId(val id: String) extends AnyVal with AbstractId
```

.. the usage of the value class wouldn't fit your case, because the class itself would still get allocated. See the [allocation summary](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html#allocation-summary):

> A value class is actually instantiated when:
>
> 1. **a value class is treated as another type.**
> 2. a value class is assigned to an array.
> 3. doing runtime type tests, such as pattern matching.

Comment: You beat me for a few seconds :)

Answer (score 1):

Some quotes from the [value classes SIP](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html) that are likely to clarify your doubts:

Value classes...

> 1. ...must have only a primary constructor with exactly one public, val
>    parameter whose type is not a value class.
> 2. ... cannot be extended by another class.

As per 1. it can not be abstract; per 2. your encoding doesn't work.

There is another caveat:

> A value class can only extend *universal traits* and cannot be extended
> itself. A universal trait is a trait that extends Any, only has defs
> as members, and does no initialization. Universal traits allow basic
> inheritance of methods for value classes, but they incur the overhead
> of allocation.

With all that in mind, based on your last snippet, this might work:

```
sealed trait AbstractId extends Any { def id: String }
final case class CatId(id: String) extends AnyVal with AbstractId
final case class DogId(id: String) extends AnyVal with AbstractId
```

But keep in mind the allocation only occurs if you want to use CatId and DogId as an AbstractId. For better understanding I recommend reading the SIP.